# Gnome 3.22: disable alt+shift keyboard layout switching

Tags: gnome, keyboard-shortcuts, gnome3, keyboard-layout

After the latest upgrade on Debian stretch, hitting `alt+shift` on my keyboard make it change layout, which breaks all my `alt+shift+<anything>` `xbindkeys` shortcuts.

I have disabled all shortcuts in Settings -> Keyboard -> Input. Still the same.

In Settings -> Languages, it is said that this `alt+shift` behaviour can be tweaked in.. Settings -> Keyboard. But `alt+shift` seems to be set nowhere there. Is it hardcoded? Is there a way `xbindkeys` can work around this?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Okay, got it: this line in my `/etc/default/keyboard`

```
XKBOPTIONS="grp:alt_shift_toggle,grp_led:scroll"
```

.. should not contain `grp:alt_shift_toggle`, which is the relevant xkb option according to [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/45499/87656).

In addition, Gnome overrides xkb options according to [this other post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/66657/87656). As a consequence, this output:

```
$ dconf read /org/gnome/desktop/input-sources/xkb-options
['grp:alt_shift_toggle','grp_led:scroll']
```

.. should not read `grp:alt_shift_toggle` on my machine either. So after I ran:

```
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/input-sources/xkb-options "['grp_led:scroll']"
```

I got my good'ol behaviour back ;)

---

I have filed this as a [bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=776570) to Gnome.

Comment: I was able to disable the `Alt + Shift` shortcut for changing keyboard layout by disabling the shortcut in `Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Typings > Modifiers-only switch to next source`. Yes, the name is quite vague but you can see that it's mapped to `Alt + Shift`.

Comment: @hb20007 I think this is the naive first try that surprisingly didn't work in my case back then. However, the navigation was a little different from the one you are describing. Which version of gnome are you talking about?

Comment: `gnome-shell --version` gives 3.18.5

Comment: @hb20007 Okay, I get it then. This post is about a problem occuring on `3.22`, which is the reason why it works fine in your case :)

Comment: For anyone else wondering why this is not working for them - don't run it as root :)

Answer (score 3):

In my case I'm using Ubuntu 18.04. I was able to solve this problem by re-configuring my keyboard setting:

```
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

Comment: Note: in Ubuntu 22.04 this configures the shortcut for when you are in TTY, but for the GUI environment you need to edit GNOME config via dconf or gnome-tweak-tool (at least that's how it is for me)

Answer (score 1):

Also this is another option in graphical mode (gnome 3.22):

1. Open the gnome 'tweak tool' or type `gnome-tweak-tool` on a terminal
2. Go to the 'Typing' tab
3. Click on 'Switching to another layout'
4. Choose your favorite shortcut avoiding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>